# Why do I get access denied when trying to list the content of a bucket in a different project than my dataflow job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-functions

I have two different project, `A` and `B`. In `A` I have a google cloud function running that triggers on messages on a pubsub topic and creates a dataflow job. This dataflow jobs list and reads the items from a specific bucket in `B`, and this is where my problem starts.

I have followed the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions#accessing-cloud-storage-buckets-across-cloud-platform-projects regarding ACL and I can see that my project user has been added as `OWNER` to the bucket I try to read from.

The error message I get is:

> 403 Forbidden\n{\n \"code\" : 403,\n \"errors\" : [ {\n \"domain\" : \"global\",\n \"message\" : \"Caller does not have storage.objects.list access to bucket bucketName.\",\n \"reason\" : \"forbidden\"\n } ],\n \"message\" : \"Caller does not have storage.objects.list access to bucket bucketName.\"\n}

Why doesn't the function have list access when project `A` has `OWNER` rights of the bucket on `B`. Does the cloud function runs with a different set of credentials than those used it the linked tutorial?

If I trigger it manually from the cli it works as expected, but then it probably uses my credentials I guess.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things here. Are you listing the files from the cloud function and than launching the dataflow job on the files? If yes, please see that the user/service account under which your cloud function is triggered has correct permission on the bucket. If no, please make sure both service accounts (cloudservices and compute engine, mentioned at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions#accessing-cloud-storage-buckets-across-cloud-platform-projects) of project A has the OWNERs permissions on project B.